# What exactly is a private MacOS framework? Why is it more difficult to add MediaRemote.framework than Accelerate.framework for example

Tags: xcode, macos

I have a roughly strong idea of what a framework is but what confuses me as a new MacOS developer (usually do iOS projects) is this idea of a "private framework". In my example I am trying to use the MediaRemote framework that is documented [here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MediaRemote.framework) and used in a few open source projects.

When seeing this I was surprised to see that indeed inside of my Mac there is a framework located here `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework` that I dont remember ever installing? So it must have came from MacOS itself?

My confusion is what exactly is this? And how is this different from if I go to add a framework such as Accelerate.framework which can be easily found by clicking the plus button and searching for it? For some reason MediaRemote does not show up in this search as though it is a different class of framework. Why do I have to manually point it to the folder instead of being able to find it here?

Even after I did point it and cleaned my build and derived data I get a linking error

```
Ld /Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bjzkxjoybnwzkkcbwnmpmbzgwfgh/Build/Products/Debug/TARGET/Versions/A/TARGET normal x86_64 (in target 'TARGET' from project 'ProjectName')
cd /Users/Username/Coding/Github/ProjectName
Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target x86_64-apple-macos10.11 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -L/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bjzkxjoybnwzkkcbwnmpmbzgwfgh/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bjzkxjoybnwzkkcbwnmpmbzgwfgh/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bjzkxjoybnwzkkcbwnmpmbzgwfgh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ProjectName.build/Debug/TARGET.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TARGET.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/TARGET/Versions/A/TARGET -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/../Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bjzkxjoybnwzkkcbwnmpmbzgwfgh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ProjectName.build/Debug/TARGET.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TARGET_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/macosx -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bjzkxjoybnwzkkcbwnmpmbzgwfgh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ProjectName.build/Debug/TARGET.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TARGET.swiftmodule -framework MediaRemote -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bjzkxjoybnwzkkcbwnmpmbzgwfgh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ProjectName.build/Debug/TARGET.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TARGET_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ProjectName-bjzkxjoybnwzkkcbwnmpmbzgwfgh/Build/Products/Debug/TARGET/Versions/A/TARGET

ld: framework not found MediaRemote
```

And I have no idea how to proceed. What even is a private framework? Why do I have to point to its folder location instead of searching it? Why is linking failing?

I have seen [projects](https://github.com/pigigaldi/Pock) that successfully use it so I dont really feel like I am trying to do something I shouldn't be able to.

Comment: Well, it's private.

Comment: What does private mean here? Not meant to be redistributed? Not safe to include? Supposed to only be used if you are Apple? Not supposed to be able to use/link?

Comment: All of the above.